# ag-grid set filter Not Filtering items excluded from Set List

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

i am building an account lookup feature using ag-grid and Angular
There is a quick filter that searches for Names
There is a set filter that filters on type/subtype

I have an ag-grid w/ 2 columns
The first column is a concatenation of account type and account subtype
The second column is account name

**it all works in the wide open use case** (user can select any account from the entire chart of accounts)

**There will be cases where I want  to constrain what the user can look up**

For this example lets assume I am constraining the Account set to be:

**Type** = Expense or Income

**Subtype** = Operating

I have the Set-Filter-Value-list defined and correctly shows the intended options ( Expense/Income and operating)
When I select just 1 of the 2 account types, the list of accounts is perfect.

however, **when I select both of them**, the ag-grid sees that I have all the filter items selected and **it includes all accounts**. not just the accounts that match the filter.

I have tried adding an extra item, just so ALL items are not selected, this mechanically solves the problem, but obviously not a production solution.

I tried setting  SuppressSelectAll.  you can observe that the SelectAll item is not available on the filter, but it does not change the behaviour of the grid.

**MY QUESTION :  IS THERE A WAY TO MAKE THE GRID HONOR THE FILTER WHEN ALL ITEMS ARE SELECTED AND FILTER OUT DATA ROWS THAT DO NOT MATCH IT?**

[image: 1 item selected, all good]

[image: both items selected, filter effectively disabled]
[image: silly work around]

Here is the component code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { COAModule } from 'src/app/coa/coa.module';
import { ChartOfAccoutsService } from 'src/app/coa/services/chart-of-accouts.service';

import{
  ColDef, ValueParserParams, ValueSetterParams,
  GridApi, GridReadyEvent, ICellRendererParams,
} from 'ag-grid-community';


import { empty, Observable, of   } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilKeyChanged, pluck
  , switchMap ,tap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';


import { getData } from './data';
import { COA_Account } from 'src/app/coa/COA_Account';
import { coaType_List } from 'src/app/coa/coaTypeList';
import { COA_Header } from 'src/app/coa/COA_Header';
 
 
export class COAlookupConfig {
  AccountTypes : string[] = ['Equity','Expense','Asset','Income','Liability']
  AccountSubTypes: string[] =['Current', 'Fixed', 'Capital Expense', 'Non-operating', 'Operating', '', 'Current','Long Term' ]
            
}
 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-look-up',
  templateUrl: './account-look-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-look-up.component.css']
})
export class AccountLookUpComponent implements OnInit {

  
  @Input() config : COAlookupConfig= new COAlookupConfig();

  private gridApi!: GridApi;
  public acctTypeSubtypes : string;

  public columnDefs: ColDef[] =[];
  public defaultColDef: ColDef = {};
  
  public rowData: any[] | null = getData();

public myCOA_Header$! : Observable<COA_Header>;  
public myTST_ctl$ : Observable<coaType_List>;
public myTST_TypeList : string[];

  constructor( private acctService : ChartOfAccoutsService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {   
          let projId: number = 4200;
          this.myCOA_Header$ = this.acctService.getCOAByProjectId(projId) ;

         //this is where i constrain the available accounts
           this.config.AccountTypes = ['Expense', 'Income']         
          this.config.AccountSubTypes = ['Operating']         

          this.myTST_ctl$ = this.acctService.get_coaTypeList(this.config.AccountTypes, this.config.AccountSubTypes).pipe(
            tap( ctl => {this.myTST_TypeList = ctl.ItemList();
                  this.defineGrid(); // now that we have the types, we can set up the grid
            })
          ) ;
          

      }

   defineGrid(){
      //call this once we have the data
  
      this.defaultColDef = {
        flex: 1,
        editable: false,
        sortable:false,
        filter:true,
         menuTabs: ['filterMenuTab'],
      };
  
      this.columnDefs = [
        // simple column, easy to understand
        { field: 'TypeSubType' 
              ,filter: 'agSetColumnFilter' 
              , filterParams:{suppressSelectAll : true, suppressMiniFilter: true,  values: this.myTST_TypeList}
              // ,getQuickFilterText: (params) => {
              //   return params.value;}
            },
    
        { field: 'Name' ,filter: false
            , suppressMenu : true
          ,   filterParams:{defaultToNothingSelected:true}} 
     
      ];
   }
   onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
     params.columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns(true);
  }
  
  onFilterTextBoxChanged() {
    this.gridApi.setQuickFilter(
      (document.getElementById('filter-text-box') as HTMLInputElement).value
    );
  }
```

Here is the HTML  template for the component

```
  <div class="example-wrapper">
      <div class="example-header">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="filter-text-box"
          placeholder="Search Account Names..."
          (input)="onFilterTextBoxChanged()"
        />
       
      </div>

    
      <ag-grid-angular 
        style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"
        class="ag-theme-balham"
        [suppressMenuHide]="true"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
        [rowData]="myCOA_Header.Accounts"    

        [cacheQuickFilter]="true"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      ></ag-grid-angular>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: i guess i could just do the constraints sever side, it seems cleaner to let the grid do all that.  It seems like I am just 1 small step from having a 100% client  side solution.

Comment: I notice ag-grid has an example that displays this same quirk.  https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-set-api/     If you choose France or Australia, you see just that country. If you pick both... you see all records (including US, etc)